# Unit test for Button with disable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test for a button that has disabled assigned to a boolean.

html looks like:

```
<button *ngIf="!data" id="createBtn" mat-button color="primary" (click)="submitNewCase()" [disabled]="disableCreate">{{ 'ACTIONS.create' | translate }}</button>
```

my unit test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CaseComponent);
 component = fixture.componentInstance;
 fixture.detectChanges();
 submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
});


  it('DisableCreate set to true disables the submit button', () => {
   component.disableCreate = true;
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(submitEl.nativeElement.disabled).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('DisableCreate set to false enables the submit button', () => {
   component.disableCreate = false;
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(submitEl.nativeElement.disabled).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

My second unit test succeeds and my first one does not. I am getting back a "Expected false to be truthy.". I cannot find where this is failing and why.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: how about data, i see *ngIf="!data" you have to set data to false, may be the button  element is not created

Comment: I gave that a shot by adding "component.data = null" before the fixture.detectChanges() but still get the same error for the first test

Comment: Can you show the configureTestingModule section, because I have a problem with [disabled] attribute in Karma tests => Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'th'

Comment: @Deunz that is most likely accurate since your are using a th element. This was for a button element that has native support for the disabled attribute. ===>https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp

Comment: Thx for input i was just missing the MatSortModule, importing it fixed the issue :)  MatTableModule is not sufficient, You've got to import The SortModule.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So after banging my head against the table a little longer it looks like I was selecting the button incorrectly. Using querySelector for button has my test succeeding. Also to @Fateh Mohamed's comment setting component.data to null is required since there is a ngIf for data on the button.

```js
    beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CaseComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
     fixture.detectChanges();
     submitEl = fixture.debugElement
    });

    it('DisableCreate set to true disables the submit button', () => {
     component.disableCreate = true;
     component.data = null;
     fixture.detectChanges();
     expect(submitEl.nativeElement.querySelector('button').disabled).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('DisableCreate set to false enables the submit button', () => {
     component.disableCreate = false;
     component.data = null;
     fixture.detectChanges();
     expect(submitEl.nativeElement.querySelector('button').disabled).toBeFalsy();
    });
```

Comment: It is necessary to define  `submitEl = fixture.debugElement` inside beforeEach() or is it safe to define it inside it()? If not then what's the difference.

Comment: I understand it that defining submitEl in beforeEach() means that I don't have to define submitEl in each it() that uses submitEl.

Comment: @BrianStanley very helpful, just what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Found another way,

in your HTML add id to button, i.e

```html
<button id="myButtonId" [disabled]="someCondition">/<button>
```

in test file get the button (by id or any other way) and check disabled state by **ng-reflect-disabled** attribute

```js
const addButton = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#myButtonId');
expect(addButton.attributes.getNamedItem('ng-reflect-disabled').value).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way I can find so far to test for the disabled state on material checkboxes.  Any others?

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers worked for me on Angular 11 so leaving my 2 cents here:

Template:

```
<div class="actions">
    <button [disabled]="loading">
        Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

Class (simplified):

```
export class SubmitComponent {
    loading = false;
}
```

Test:

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
let component: SubmitComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<SubmitComponent>;

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SubmitComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should disable on load', () => {
    fixture.componentInstance.loading = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const button: HTMLButtonElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.actions > button')).nativeElement;
    expect(button.attributes.getNamedItem('ng-reflect-is-disabled')?.value).toEqual('true');
    // or 
    expect(button.attributes.getNamedItem('ng-reflect-is-disabled')?.value).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
let component: SubmitComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<SubmitComponent>;

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SubmitComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should disable on load', () => {
    fixture.componentInstance.loading = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const buttons= fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
      '.actions > button'
    );
  buttons.forEach(button => {
      expect(button.attributes['disabled'].value).toEqual('true');
    });
    // or in false case .
   buttons.forEach(button => {
      expect(button.attributes['disabled']).toBeUndefined();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using the @ngneat/spectator package and testing values declared as @Input(), use `spectator.setInput({ myInputValue: true })` instead of `component.myInputValue = true;` in your tests.